# How to compile and run source code on the Github server online?

Tags: testing, github, compilation

I´m looking for way (a GitHub extension) to compile and/or run snippets of source code (preferable C, C++, and Go - partwise Ruby) immediately on the Github server online in a webbrowser without downloading the relative file(s) or the repository to a specific client and compile and execute it there.

I have been searching for a question according to this here on Stack Overflow but I did not find one. When I seek in a search engine, I only get solutions to download the file(s) and compile it on my computer.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use the open-source [RunMyCode Online tool](https://github.com/shatgupt/runmycode.online) to test source code in C, C++, Java, Nodejs, Python, Ruby, PHP, Go, Kotlin or Scala immediately on the Github website, which is supported for Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera.